# Owl carousel show a different image on mobile

Tags: html, owl-carousel

I've been using PageSpeed Insights from google to see how I can improve my website and the main point I'm getting is that my images are to large for mobile users. Currently I'm using the owl-carousel which came with the template I'm using.

Google automatically supplied me with resized images but I've got no idea how to implement these into the carousel. I tried something like https://github.com/teleject/hisrc but after trying it in multiple ways it just kept removing the images completely.

Anyone knows how I can automatically change the source depending on the screensize?

For instance on the desktop I'm showing mainimage.jpg and I would like to show mainimage-mobile.jpg if the screen gets smaller instead of just resizing it.

Here is my carousel:

(The `style="position: relative"` is required in order for the menu to stay on top of the image for chrome users)

```
<div class="line animated fadeIn "style="position: relative">
    <div class=" s-12 l-9 center cushycms" style="position: relative">
        <div id="owl-demo" class="owl-carousel owl-theme  margin-bottom">
        <div class="item" style="position: relative"><img style="position: relative" src="img/image1.jpg" alt="image"></div>
        <div class="item" style="position: relative"><img style="position: relative" src="img/image2.jpg" alt="image"></div>
        <div class="item" style="position: relative"><img style="position: relative" src="img/image3.jpg" alt="image"></div>
        <div class="item" style="position: relative"><img style="position: relative" src="img/image4.jpg" alt="image"></div>
        <div class="item" style="position: relative"><img style="position: relative" src="img/image5.jpg" alt="image"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Not sure if this is of any help but this is the template I'm using http://www.myresponsee.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `<picture>` element instead of just `<img>`.

For example:

```
<picture>
    <source srcset="mainimage-mobile.jpg" media="(max-width: 640px)">
    <img srcset="mainimage.jpg">
</picture>
```

In the above code the default `mainimage.jpg` is used, but once the screen is narrower that 641px - `mainimage-mobile.jpg` is used by the browser automatically.

The only problem with this approach might be browser support http://caniuse.com/#search=picture. But on the other hand, you could also include a javascript polyfill. https://github.com/scottjehl/picturefill

Comment: For some reason it only seems to work on firefox, on chrome it still displays the largest image. But thanks for helping me out :)

Comment: I am glad it helped at least partially :) On the newest Chrome browser it should work quite well. I can guess 2 potential reasons why it doesn't work on Chrome in your case: 1. Chrome version too old? 2. Chrome window size you are testing on is bigger that 640px?

Comment: Have you checked the "Network" tab on Chrome Developer tools to see which exactly image does it download?

Comment: I already fixed it, the first example they gave didn't work but the second one where it uses the <picture> tag did. Thanks again :)

Comment: How about performance and loading 2 images specially on mobile? or would you load dynamically?

Answer (score -1):

You may be looking for width: width_you_want%;
This makes it dependent on the screen size, the width being relative to that.

Documentation: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/width